# Is there a way to automatically generate a string given an input of another string?

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp

I am fairly new to data science in general, and I'm wondering if it is possible to use machine learning/natural language processing to generate definitions for various terms.  My team has recently been tasked with the delivery of a business glossary and using ML/NLP has been an idea that my manager wants to pursue.

I'm wondering if, for example, it is possible to write an algorithm that takes a 1-4 word string as an input and generates a 'good' definition, with good being defined by a statement of what the term is/means without being circular (e.g. the definition for 'Account' should be simply be 'Account' or 'An account').

I've been exploring various Python libraries (nltk, gensim, scikit-learn) and reading tutorials on how this could possibly be done, but as you can tell I'm a novice.  I've gone through the [Natural Language Processing Fundamentals in Python](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/natural-language-processing-fundamentals-in-python) course on Datacamp which is very helpful in building a basic classifier algorithm but that's all I've really been able to do.

My first idea is that I could write something which consumes various corpora.  I'm in Finance so my thoughts on the type of corpora would be the [FIBO Glossary](https://spec.edmcouncil.org/static/glossary/) and the various business glossaries which already exist in-house.

So basically, I'm just wondering if

- What I'm trying to do is even possible
- If it is, if anyone here knows of a or use case where this has been implemented or even what the name of such an algorithm, function is, as that would make looking for resources easier.

Thank you for your help.